# How do you walk across a 10' x 10' hole using two 9' boards?

Tags: geometry, situation

Given a 10' x 10' hole which is very deep, how do you walk across the hole using two boards that are each 9' long?

You can't jump, pole vault across, nail the boards together, or go around the hole.

You can start on any side you like, but once you start to cross, you must stay on the two boards. No stepping off on the sides.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! The question isn't very clear as stated. For example, is the hole near one edge, or it's surrounding the whole square?

Comment: Updated it to make it more clear.  :)

Comment: How wide is the hole?

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate, but I can't find one on the site anywhere so

Comment: Wait a moment, "in side of it" means "inside of it"? If so, that mispelling is creating a lot of confusion, I guess

Comment: My first thought was to do something with placing the boards diagonally, but if you can't walk on the side-edges, then it seems you wouldn't be able to brace a board against them, either. Or can you use the side-edges to hold up a board, despite not being able to walk on them?

Comment: Also: "you can start on any side you like" -- in that case, I choose to start on the side that I'm trying to get to ;)

Comment: In my mind for some reason there were walls either side. Gah!

Comment: If *we* can't travel to the side of the hole, why can we support the *boards* there? It's a bizarre and arbitrary rule.

Comment: Added "You can start on any side you like, but once you start you must stay on the two boards. No stepping off on the sides."

Comment: Use the boards as stilts. With enough practice, the right speed and good timing you can stride (walk) across the hole without jumping or vaulting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You put the first board

> at a 45 degree angle across one corner

of the hole. Then you put the other one

> with one end on the first board and the other end on the side of the hole.

Thanks to Julian Rosen and Geobits for their insight on how my drawing was bad. I updated it to be more accurate:

> [image]

Comment: How does that help you cross the hole with the two boards?  It appears that your solution leaves them behind.

Comment: @Anon I guess you should ask OP to clarify his question. When he use the word *with*, I guess he means *using* and not that you need to carry them along.

Comment: Updated question.  "using"

Comment: Cute diagram. But if I can't walk around the hole, how do I get the green board in place and how do I get onto the green board (which I think is about 5 feet away from the corner) to place the red board? The question isn't clear about what parts of the sides of the hole are accessible.

Comment: You can lay the first board down (green) by standing close to one corner,  then walk onto it with the second board (red) in hand. Then lay the second board down (as shown in the diagram), then walk onto that board and across the hole.

Comment: Update question "start on any side you choose".

Comment: If the hole is a square 10 feet on a side and the boards are 9 feet, then this won't quite reach. The distance from the center of the green board to the upper left corner is $10\sqrt{2}-9/2\approx9.64$.

Comment: @JulianRosen Yea, the red board shouldn't go to the corner, but just straight vertical from some (among many) point along the green board. The diagram shows it wrong, but the text doesn't specify that it goes to the corner.

Comment: If there is room enough around the hole and the edges are stable enough to support the boards, why not simply walk around?

Comment: @jarnbjo For the same reason you can't pole vault across: the rules state you can't.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple solution that lets you take both boards with you:

> [image]

You're not allowed to walk around the hole, but clearly there must be *some* kind of a ledge on each side of the hole that you can use to support the end of a board on, even if it's too narrow to walk on.  (Otherwise *none* of the answers work, and I'm fairly sure that the problem is unsolvable.)  So just

> place one board so that it reaches from the side you're on to one of the ledges, about halfway across.  Pick up the second board and walk along the first to the ledge, then place the second board down so it reaches from the ledge to the other side.  Step across to the second board (you can make the gap between the boards arbitrarily small, so this should not be a problem), pick up the first one and walk to the other side.

**Ps.** Note that this puzzle, as stated above, is a much simplified version of the classic [moat-crossing problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Moat-CrossingProblem.html).  In the original problem, to which [lorimer's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15710) would be a correct solution, the "hole" is actually an L-shaped corner in a moat, and you need to get from the outside to the inside corner of the L.  This rules out "trivial" answers like mine and [A.D.'s](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15709) (but also prevents you from picking up both boards after you've crossed).

Comment: Wouldn't this work with 1 board as well?

Comment: @jpmc26: Only if the ledge is wide enough to stand on while you pick up the board and move it.

Comment: That would also have to be the case to take both boards with you to the other side, though, as your answer suggests. ;)

Comment: @jpmc26: Not really. With two boards, you can stand on one board while putting down / picking up the other. You never have to actually stand on the ledge.

Answer (score 6):

> Like this -- you put one board at an angle, then the other across.
>
>   [image]

Comment: This is a good solution to the [original problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Moat-CrossingProblem.html), of which the puzzle asked above is a simplified / corrupted variant. +1.

Answer (score 3):

> Use one board to connect the south edge to the west-ward/east-ward edge. Use the second board and connect it to the first board to reach the end.