# Well Escape Puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle, geometry

There is a well as shown in figure. A stand is present in the middle of the well and man is standing on the stand. The height of stand is the same as the depth of well. The distance between the boundaries of stand and well is 1.1 m. The man is provided with two rods of 1 m each.The man has to come out of the well using the two rods. How is this possible? Solve it out.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is not a [logic-puzzle]: that tag is only for puzzles which require logical deduction. I've removed it for you.

Comment: Similar (possibly duplicate): http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/

Comment: If you're confused by the exposition, picture "an island ringed by lava." The diagram shows the situation from above. The depth of the well is not important, all the action happens in the plane.

Comment: It's not possible, by which I mean that the sticks offer no advantage. The man can get from the edge to the centre, but not from the centre to the edge. Equally, the rods would need considerable bearing, otherwise they would roll off when under deflection. I don't think you've thought this through ;-). In fact, if the radius of the stand is larger than ca. 150mm, it doesn't work anyway! On the other hand, it is of course easy to cover 1.1m from a standing jump.

Comment: @Strawberry: I make 0.2m the point where the central radius is such that the sticks are the exact length they need to be (ie ignoring the fact that they'd need some overlap, etc.) Also you could attach the sticks to one another to create a single placable item if you were in the centre. You don't need to place the outer one first.

Comment: @Chris what would you use to attach the two sticks? The question doesn't mention you having anything you could use to do that. And if you're going to stretch the question, you might as well just jump out.

Comment: @ffao: I would have said that if you are worrying about the practicalties of the person's situation such as how you might attach two sticks together then as you say that leads to the jump out solution. Given the question is tagged as calculation-puzzle and geometry which suggests we aren't worrying about physical practicalities and in fact just have a story as a bit of flavour for what is in essence a mathematical exercise I was probably foolish in my attempt to suggest a solution to a practicality problem.

Comment: Yeah, this is totally jumpable. We need some unjumpable distances—preferably over lava—to get our puzzling adrenaline flowing.

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea:

> [image]

Calculation:

> He places one of the rods on the well boundary, so that its both end is laying on the boundary, but the middle is above the well itself (the vertical rod on my picture). The middle of this rod is $\sqrt{(1.1^2-0.5^2)} \approx 0.98$ meters away from the stand, thus he can lay the second rod with its ends at the stand and the middle of the first rod, and walk out on them.

Comment: Correct obviously, but how do you do that?  I would just jump it after both of my sticks fell down the well. :)

Comment: yes, unless we don't assume the man's arms are long enough this is much more a method about how to get to the stand in the middle.

Comment: @elias that ocurred to me too. Perhaps there's treasure on the island you want to reach.

Comment: For this to work, the stand must have a radius too small to balance upon. And the man must have very long arms.

Comment: @Strawberry, how does the radius of the stand affect the solution? Could you please explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the stand has radius more than 0.1m a single rod is long enough

Comment: No, @Jasen. The 1.1m given is not the radius of the well, but the distance between the stand and the well boundary, as the question states.

Comment: The distance from the edge of the stand to the edge of the well is 1100m. This means that the radius of the well must be more than 1100m. So, let's say the stand has a radius of 250mm, and the well therefore has a radius of 1350mm. Under these circumstances, an isoceles triangle of base 1m and height 1m could not touch two points on the wall of the well, and reach the stand.

Comment: You're right, @Strawberry. My solution works in case of an ideally small stand.

Comment: Not ideally small. Just 0.2m or smaller - that's enough for somebody to stand (Though not comfortable).