The bridge is too short
You just got the job as the new gardener in the kings beautiful garden. The garden contains a square fountain with a square island in the middle. The fountain is 16 by 16 meters and the island is 10 by 10 m exactly in the center. See the badly drawn and not to scale image below.

To fullfill your gardener duties you need to reach the island and you would prefer to keep your feet dry. Searching around the garden, you find a big wooden board. The board is solid enough to easily carry your weight and the edges of the fountain and the island form a solid stone edge so you think you can just lay the board across and walk over.
Alas, it turns out the board is too short: it is 2.9 m long, 15 cm wide and 3 cm thick. You search a little longer and find a second board, again hoping this would be the missing bridge but it turns out the second board has the exact same dimensions as the first one. There are no other tools or gadgets to be found in the garden. So how do you get to the island without getting wet?
I saw a puzzle with this basic idea in a puzzle book many years ago but I unfortunately don't remember the book.

I'd be amazed if this hasn't already been posted here somehow before - definitely a classic in my mind! Still, I can't spot it, so perhaps it was time it was posted after all?!

Very similar to this one, at least: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/how-do-you-walk-across-a-10-x-10-hole-using-two-9-boards/ and one of the answers matches the original variant.

@hexomino I agree, this is very similar, essentially the same solution idea.

If your name happens to be Mike Powell, you don't need Maths :)

It is definitely an old classic: Moat-crossing problem

+1 for the badly drawn and not to scale image.

Solution:

 

Explanation:

 if left/bottom is the origin, red point has both coordinates $\frac{2.9}{2*\sqrt{2}}$, which is approximately (1.02,1.02).
 Hence from red point to green square, we have the diagonal of a 2m side square (actually a bit smaller), which is $2*\sqrt{2} = ~2.82m$  which fits the second board size
 We even have a bit of margin to shift the boards to prevent them from toggling


I don't think toggle is the right word, but I can't work out what you mean, so I can't suggest another choice.

If the fountain is not very deep (~1m or less) and the boards aren't too slippery:

Lay one board down perpendicular to the fountain edge, with one end resting on the fountain edge and one end submerged in the water. Now, place the second board on top of it, with one end on the part of the first board that's sticking out of the water, and the other end on the island. So long as the first board sticks out of the water at least 0.1m away from the edge, and the boards aren't too slippery, this will work:


 
(side  view)

If the fountain is less than 15cm deep:

 Just turn each board on its side, place them in the water staggered slightly, and walk across like a balance beam.

As a bonus, both of these solutions work for a fountain of any shape, so long as there is even a single point where the gap is 3m wide.

That is a very clever idea, nice.

I love these kind of out to the box solutions

If the water is not too deep, place one of the boards in the bottom of the fountain, halfway between the fountain edge and the island. Hold on tight to the top of the other end of the board, like a pole vault, and make big jump until you land safely on the island.

Don't forget to keep hold of the board if you want to make the return trip.
